# How to make Array<Any> equatable?

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, swift4.1

I have a following decodable class:

```
class Sample: Decodable {
    var something: Array<Any>?
}

extension Sample: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Sample, rhs: Sample) -> Bool {
        return rhs.something ?? [] == lhs.something ?? []
    }
}
```

Gives me the error type `Any` does not conform to the protocol.

For everyone information the object type in `Array` will be determined only at runtime once I receive response.

Need help.

Comment: That makes no sense. The whole concept of comparison exists only for known quantities.

Comment: ... and you cannot decode `Any` *any*way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not make `Array<Any>` as `Equatable` or `Decodable` because both `protocols` will need the `Array's` `Element` type to be `Equatable` or `Decodable` and `Any` does not fulfill this requirement.

What you can do is, create your own custom `class` to fulfill the above requirements as below,

```
class MyAny: Equatable, Decodable {

    static func == (lhs: MyAny, rhs: MyAny) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }

    var id: Int
}

class Sample: Decodable {

    var something: Array<MyAny>?
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kamran. I can try this method.